# Array values to check another array values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array `$minus`

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "people" 
           [1]=> string(7) "friends" 
           [2]=> string(8) "siblings" 
         }
```

And I have an array `$user`

```
array(3) { ["people"]=> string(3) "100" 
           ["friends"]=> string(2) "10" 
           ["siblings"]=> string(2) "57" 
         }
```

I can get the values of `$user` by using the values of `$minus` like,

```
echo $user[$minus[0]] . ', ' . $user[$minus[1]] . ', ' . $user[$minus[2]];
// Would echo: 100, 10, 57
```

But how can I get the values of `$user` by using the values of `$minus` into a new array, the new array should be like,

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "100" 
           [1]=> string(2) "10" 
           [2]=> string(2) "57" 
         }
```

I have tried using `foreach` loops but can never get it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($minus as $key=>$value) {
  $new_array[$key] = $user[$value];
}
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly, thank you for this. Is there any good links for documentation on this?

Comment: The PHP documentation is always brilliant - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php.

Comment: It is better to initialize the array before the foreach.  
$new_array= array();

Comment: You agree but I am unvotted :P Just kidding

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), PHP >= 5.3 only

```
$new_array = array_map(function($item) use ($user) {return $user[$item];}, $minus);
```

Comment: @novactown.com what's your PHP version?

Comment: Thanks for this, in terms of speed would this be better or a for each loop? I am guessing this as it doesn't need to iterate through the items or does it?

Comment: @novactown.com It should be faster, but you should probably benchmark the two. Also, if you use this in several places, you might wanna make it a named function instead of an anonymous one, as I'm not sure how the interpreter optimizes it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_array= array();
foreach ($minus as $key => $value){
 $new_array[$key] =  $user[$value];
    }
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = array($user[$minus[0]], $user[$minus[1]], $user[$minus[2]]);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's not the best solution - it only works as long as the keys have that name, and there are exactly 3 members of the array. If the key names or the size of the array change, this will have to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$minus = array(0 => "people",
               1 => "friends",
               2 => "siblings"
              );

$user = array("people"   => "100",
              "friends"  => "10",
              "siblings" => "57"
             );


$newArray = $minus;
array_walk($newArray,function(&$item, $key, $prefix) { $item = $prefix[$item]; },$user);

var_dump($newArray);
```